# In my rails project, Why are my media queries only responsive in development?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, media-queries

I added a background color to the different resolution sizes so I can more easily see the changes during collapse. When I reduce and expand the window in development , I am able to see the color changes happening. So the responsivness is effective in development. When i send the project to production, our phones or tablet do not pick up on the custom CSS. Am i missing something from the  tag ? or am I implementing it wrong ? I have tried the following

```
@media screen only ()
@media screen and ()
@media all and ()
```

they all work in development....but nothing happens in production.

here is my bootstrap_and_overrides.css file

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";

.hero-unit{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}
body {
    padding-top: 41px;
}

.span12 {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0px;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
    filter: none;
}
.form-horizontal{
  /* text-align:right; */
  text-align:left;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #new_customer {background: green; margin-left:-20% !important; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #new_customer {background: black; margin-left:-20% !important; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    #new_customer {background: red; margin-left:8% !important; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait); {
    #new_customer {background: blue; margin-left: 21% !important; }
}


@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";




// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";

// Glyphicons
//@import "twitter/bootstrap/sprites.less";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;
```

Here is my application.html.erb file that contains the head tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Solano</title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
    <body style="background-color:#93df75">

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="brand" href="#">SolanoSprinklers.net</a>
                  <div class="nav-collapse">
                      <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><%= link_to "Home",home_index_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sprinkler Services",home_services_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Testimonials",home_testimonials_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Contact Us",home_contact_path %></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!--        <div class="hero-unit" style="background-color:#93df75; height:15px">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>text will go here</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>-->

        <div class="container" style="padding-bottom:25px">
            <div style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #00cc00">
            <%= image_tag 'Solano2.png' %>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span10">
                    <%= yield %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
       <hr>
        <footer style="background-image: url(assets\images\grass.png)">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                <h6>Copyright &copy; 2014 Solano Sprinklers</h6>
                </div>

                <div class="span4">
              <h6>About Us</h6>
              <p><b>South Chicagolands's Premiere Residential and Commercial Lawn Irrigation Installation and Repair</b> </p>
                </div>

                <div class="span4">
              <h6>Navigation</h6>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="span2">
                <h6>Follow Us</h6>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer> 
    </body>
</html>
```

here is production.rb

```
Solano::Application.configure do


 # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can see the updated CSS code in production by viewing the style.css in your head? Maybe it's an issue with recompiling assets.

Comment: No , just in development. IN production ( When I view on a tablet/phone) nothing happens. Thats my problem

Comment: @AlecSanger might be right.  Make sure your `production.rb` is configured correctly and your precompile assets with `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Comment: You're using '\'s in your urls... that doesn't look right. Also, you should be using [helper methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) in your view templates to generate asset paths and urls: `background-image: <%= asset_path 'grass.png' %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say it is working in development but not production, and the fact that you are modifying assets leads me to believe that those assets are being served properly on the server. One way to fix this would be to precompile the assets before pushing but this can get annoying after awhile.

Use the [`rails_12factor`](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and run `bundle install`. This will automatically precompile the assets when you push code into production.

Comment: @AlecSanger I tried both `gem 'rails_12factor'`and `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` production is still not responding. I added my `production.rb` file above. Im new to rails and wouldnt be able to to confirm that it is configured correctly. I removed my stylesheets/application.css file because `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` was failing and pointed at the file. It is not being used, so I put it to the side and the command passed

Comment: I just added back the `application.css` file to the assets/stylsheets. Although I do not have any css in that file, it caused all twitter bootstrap elements to be removed. So I added it back in which means my rake assets:precompile will throw this error `Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap                                                           Load paths:
  C:/Sites/solano
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.2/a
sets/stylesheets
  (in C:/Sites/solano/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):42`

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?  I am facing exactly the same